# Using RoboGuice 4 without injectMembers() in each activity

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, annotations, roboguice

I am getting started with RoboGuice 4. Following the example in [github](https://github.com/kelsos/kotlin-roboguice/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/kelsos/kotlinroboguice/MainActivity.kt) I created the `Module` file, registered it in `AndroidManifest.xml` and created some interface and implementation. Also added the code to MainActivity:

```
override onCreate( ..
    RoboGuice.setupBaseApplicationInjector(application)
    RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectMembers(this)
```

It all works well, but does this mean I have to add this code everywhere I use `@Inject`? Is there any way to avoid it?